# Can I evaluate additive interaction for GLMM

Tags: interaction, glmm, biostatistics, count-data

I am currently running a GLMM (log-link function) examining the effect of two treatments on the instances of an arthropod. I seek to determine if there is **additive** interaction between the two dichotomous treatments (A and B) on arthropod counts.

glmer.nb(Counts ~ Treatment A + Treatment B + (1|Plot))

Questions:

1. Is it appropriate to evaluate the IRR outputs for the presence of interaction on an additive scale?
2. If so, how do I calculate the 95%CI and p-value of the additive interaction

I have been using the simple epidemiological methodology (AB - A0 - 0B + 00), however I am uncertain that it is the correct approach for GLMM. How do I determine if the interaction is significant. Appreciate any help you may offer.

Comment: What do you mean by **additive interaction**?

Comment: I want to determine if the effect of one exposure influences the effect of the other exposure (is there an enhanced effect of integrating treatments compared to the additive effect of individual treatments). Is AB (integrated) - A0 (treatment A-only) - 0B (treatment B-only) + 00 (control) >,<,= 0?